# Validation without using Data Annotation in mvc 4 razor engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to perform validation without using Data Annotation as i have used EF in n-tier MVC 4 razor architecture. And also Data Annotations doesn't work for EF controls.You all can see my code here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(CreateUser obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //    
    }
}
```

and `ModalState.Isvalid` doesn't work. How can I resolve this?

Comment: DataAnnotations doesn't work for EF controls, what?

Comment: Please make your question more clear. It makes no sense!! What is "Data Annotations doesn't work for EF controls"? How could you get an invalid ModelState if there is nothing that sets it?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for are cases where the DataAnnotation validation will not give you the flexibility you need.

For example, I need an address which can either be selected via a dropdown or entered. 
If one of the entered address lines is there then all of them need to be there.
That's tough to check with DataAnnotations alone.

What I've done in the past is do the validation once control is returned to the controller but before the ModelState.IsValid is checked.

This allows custom/complex validation in the controller

You can use then

```
    ModelState.AddModelError("PostalCode", "The postal code is missing.");
```

to modify the ModelState (Make it invalid) which can then return control to the view after checking ModelState.IsValid